# SQL to extract a part of string

Tags: sql, string, t-sql

I am trying to extract timestamp out of a filename. The filename looks like `'Relabels for 10-19-2019 15-16-24'`. I want to extract the timestamp i.e., `15-16-24` out of that filename. Can anyone help me with the SQL query? I tried using substring but substring doesn't work for all filenames.

Comment: 15-16-24 is a time stamp???

Comment: What filenames did you have a problem with?

Comment: "I tried something with other data and it didn't work, but I won't share the code, the data, or how it failed" doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

If `15-16-24` is intended to be `15:16:24` then I understand it as a time.  You can extract it by using `right()`:

```
select right(filename, 8)
```

You can even convert it to a time:

```
select try_convert(time, replace(right(filename, 8), '-', ':'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be very explicit and use `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` and `SUBSTRING`.

```
declare @dt_string varchar(100) = right('Relabels for 10-19-2019 15-16-24', (8+2)+1+(6+2));

select DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
  SUBSTRING(@dt_string,7,4), -- year
  SUBSTRING(@dt_string,1,2), -- month
  SUBSTRING(@dt_string,4,2), -- day
  SUBSTRING(@dt_string,12,2), -- hour
  SUBSTRING(@dt_string,15,2), -- minute
  SUBSTRING(@dt_string,18,2), -- second
  0 -- millisecond
  ) as dt_parsed;
```

```
dt_parsed
2019-10-19 15:16:24.000
```